# Convert a datatable string from Azure ML WS to an actual Datatable C# Object?

Tags: c#, azure, datatable, azure-machine-learning-service

Basically I'm receiving an output like this from my azure ws output:

```
{
    'Results': {
        'WSOutput': {
            'type': 'table',
            'value': {
                'ColumnNames': ['ID', 'Start', 'Ask', 'Not', 'Passed', 'Suggest'],
                'ColumnTypes': ['Int32', 'Int32', 'Int32', 'Double', 'Int64', 'Int32'],
                'Values': [['13256025', '25000', '19000', '0.35', '1', '25000']]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The string, as you can see, has the info to create a datatable object. Now, I can't seem to find an easy way to cast it to an actual datatable POCO. I'm able to manually code a parser with Newtonsoft.Json.Linq but there has to be an easier way.

Does anybody know how? I can't seem to find anything on the net.

Comment: What do you mean by an "actual datatable POCO"?

Comment: @mason POCO = plain old CLR object (Datatable C# object)

Comment: I'm quite familiar with what a POCO is. I'm also familiar with a [System.Data.DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx). What I'm not familiar with is an "actual datatable POCO".

Comment: I meant a datatable C# object, didn't think it through, apologies

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by that? Do you mean a custom C# class? Or do you mean a `System.Data.DataTable`?

Comment: System.Data.DataTable ;). Thanks a lot btw mason!

Comment: In that case, a DataTable isn't really a POCO. Typically when you say POCO, you mean a simple object with a couple properties. A System.Data.DataTable is a very complex and dynamic class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a open source online gernator on the net (http://jsonutils.com/). Copy paste your result will give you that:

```
 public class Value
    {
        public IList<string> ColumnNames { get; set; }
        public IList<string> ColumnTypes { get; set; }
        public IList<IList<string>> Values { get; set; }
    }

    public class WSOutput
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Results
    {
        public WSOutput WSOutput { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public Results Results { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It's also possible directly in Visual Studio: "Edit" >" Paste Special" > "Paste JSON as Classes"

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question even though martin's should be the one that's accepted.

I ended up coding my own horrible transformer like this:

```
var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(jsonn);
            var length = parsedJson["Results"]["WSOutput"]["value"]["Values"][0].Count();
            IDictionary<string, object> flexibleJson = new ExpandoObject();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                string colName = parsedJson["Results"]["WSOutput"]["value"]["ColumnNames"][i].ToString();
                string colValue = parsedJson["Results"]["WSOutput"]["value"]["Values"][0][i].ToString(); // single result for now
                flexibleJson.Add(colName, colValue);
            }

            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flexibleJson);
```

And then using that, you can deserialize it with json.net to a datatable =)